# Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: java, android, kotlin, firebase, google-cloud-messages

С помощью Firebase отправляю сообщение на телефон через Cloud Messaging. Все работает. Сообщение отправил, тыкнул на телефоне по нему, открылась программа. Но проблема в том, что надо запустить не стартовую активити, а другую. Везде один и тот же код:

```
val intent = Intent(this,Testing::class.java)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,1,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

    val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "MyNotifications")
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentText(body)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

    val manager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)
    manager.notify(999, builder.build())
```

К примеру, в этой ситуации есть Testing активити, но открывается первая - MainActivity. Будет ли часть кода, где я создаю pendingIntent или не будет, разницы - нет. Открывается одна и та же активити - MainActivity. Что сделать, чтобы можно было открыть какую-то конкретную активити ?

Answer (score 0):

То что вы описываете, это дефолтное поведение при минимальной интеграции библиотек FCM.
Теперь надо идти дальше и расширить `FirebaseMessagingService`, добавив свое поведение, как обьясняется здесь:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Код библиотеки FCM сам по себе не запускает ничего в вашем приложении.